# binding combobox inside gridview

Tags: gridview, binding, combobox, gridviewcolumn

I have a listview that holds a gridview.
I have a seperated list with Devices list.
Every device holds a list of Connectors. 
    every connector has a list of Tags. 
        every Tag has a property X.

Currently, when I choose device from the devices list, I am showing the connectors of the device in the gridview.
The gridview holds a column with ConnectorName and a column with Combobox that suppose to show every Tag's X property.
I want to fill every combobox of every connector with the Tags.X property.

The code is the following:

// The GridView holds the connectors of the selected device from device list with two columns: connector name and combobox to show tags.X value of every connector

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lstDevices, Path=SelectedItem.Connectors}"
            Background="Transparent"
            SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="200"
                            Header="Connector Name"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ConnectorName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Connectors}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Connector.IOTags.InputSignalType}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks, Ido